# Select random arrays from a stack of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array `np_arr` with a shape as such

```
(3787, 256, 256)
```

I want to sample 20 random arrays from the existing array such that

```
(20, 256, 256)
```

I tried

`import random`

`new_array = random.sample(np_arr,20)`

but that didn't work.

How do I go about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.random.choice`to randomly choose indices of the first dimension, then index your array with it:

```
import numpy as np

# Generating random data
rand_arr = np.random.rand(3787, 256, 256)

rand_idx = np.random.choice(rand_arr.shape[0], 20)
rand_arr[rand_idx]
# > shape = (20, 256, 256)

# In one line:
rand_arr[np.random.choice(rand_arr.shape[0], 20)]
```